# is there a shortcut key to find a function in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

lets say i have a function called simpleFunction(); that i call a bunch of times in my program.  i don't want to do a ctrl+f to find it, is there a faster way to just jump straight to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse</kbd> on an occurence of the function will take you to it.

Answer (score 5):

use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> for quick member lookup

Answer (score 3):

Use `ctrl + o` to find any method in the class and use `ctrl + shift + r` to find any file. Also if you are on the particular method you can just `press F3` and it will take you to that method.

For more short-cuts about Eclipse refer [Eclipse ShortCuts](http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2011/06/eclipse-shortcuts-1-eclipse-shortcuts-2.html)